# Supervisord logs; how to separate log messages into a new file for each execution?

Tags: supervisord

I am using ***supervisord*** to keep our application server service alive if it fails, and to auto-start the service on machine load.

Currently all the logs go into the same long-running file, which is a pain when trying to triage faults. I want the log files to be distinct across program executions/restarts.

I couldn't find any configuration for separating log content, except by setting the files max-size, which creates a new file and may keep the old file depending on your configuration; this doesn't have the clean separation across executions I am looking for.

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this option doesn't exist. Is there a reason why you cannot just have your program output a distinctive log entry upon start? This would make it trivial to identify each execution's logs and split them up retroactively if needed.

Comment: The problem is worse in the stderr stream because our logger puts dates and times on each logged line in stdout. We could output a stderr message on start with current date/time, but I had hoped there would be something a little more elegant :(